# Why must I reopen my pdf viewer to see document additions?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I'm using a mac with latex-suite. Everything is working well, except that after hitting `\ls` or `\lv` to view my pdf output, if I made additional changes to my tex file, I must first close the pdf before these additional changes are displayed by hitting `\ls` or `\lv` a second time.

Here are some changes I introduced to my latex-suite environment. Perhaps they (though I don't see how) account for this fix?

In compiler.vim (which is under the following directory)

`/Users/Muno/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite`, I extended the regex in a conditional of the forward search function. The regex matches the `viewer` variable (which is really `g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf`) with potential file viewers (in this case Skim, PDFView or Texniscope).

```
 elseif (has('macunix') && (viewer =~ '^ *\(Skim\|PDFView\|TeXniscope\)\( \|$\)'))
376                 " We're on a Mac using a traditional Mac viewer
377 
378                 
379                 if viewer =~ '^ *\(Skim\)'
380 
381                                 let execString .= '/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline '
382                                 let execString .= join([linenr, target_file, sourcefileFull])
```

to

```
 elseif (has('macunix') && (viewer =~ '^ *\(Skim\|PDFView\|TeXniscope\|open -a Skim\)\( \|$\)'))
376                 " We're on a Mac using a traditional Mac viewer
377 
378                 echo viewer
379                 if viewer =~ '^ *\(Skim\|open -a Skim\)'
380 
381                                 let execString .= '/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline '
382                                 let execString .= join([linenr, target_file, sourcefileFull])
```

And my .vimrc is as follows:

```
" REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke Latex-Suite when you open a tex file.
filetype plugin on

" IMPORTANT: win32 users will need to have 'shellslash' set so that latex
" can be called correctly.
set shellslash

" IMPORTANT: grep will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
" search in a singe file. This will confuse Latex-Suite. Set your grep
" program to always generate a file-name.
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

" OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
filetype indent on

" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
let g:tex_flavor='latex'

" This changes the pdf viewer from some other viewer to Preview.app

let g:Tex_TreatMacViewerAsUNIX = 1
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = "open -a Skim"
let g:Tex_ViewRule_ps = "open -a Preview.app"

    " Command-R will write, compile, and forward search--thanks to
    " http://reference-man.blogspot.com/2011/09/fully-integrated-latex-in-macvim.html
    " preview, switch back to main window
    map <D-r> :w<cr><leader>ll<leader>ls
    imap <D-r> <ESC><D-r>



"Coloration
colorscheme darkblue

set number                      "Line numbers are good
"let mapleader=","
```

Comment: Some PDF viewers will update the view when the file is changed, but apparently not the one you're using. I believe Mac Preview does update automatically.